# CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class

Tags: objective-c, core-data, initializer

I have a little damn problem with CoreData. I want to insert a new Object, so I first have to create one. This is done by that code:

```
Challenges *newChallenge = [[Challenges alloc] init];
[newChallenge setName:@"TestChallenge"];
[newChallenge setRounds:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:12]];
[newChallenge setShots:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:5]];
[newChallenge setDate:[NSDate date]];
```

But however after the alloc init I get this error:

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Challenges'
```

What the hack is going wrong?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think the problem is that Challenges is a `NSManagedObject` class and you need the designated initializer:

```
initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:
```

instead of

```
Challenges *newChallenge = [[Challenges alloc] init];
```

[Read More..](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html)

Comment: I think you meant *designated* initializer.

Comment: @jiehr: Of course I meant designated initializer - many thanks! (I have edited the answer)

Answer (score 30):

In case you ask yourself "OK, so how to I get that entity?" (like I did), you do this by using the entityForName method like so:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Challenges" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

Challenges *newChallenge = [[Challenge alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Hope this helps, this thread has helped me a lot!

Answer (score 14):

`NSManagedObject` cannot be just `alloc`/`init` like you would normally do with an `NSObject`. As a matter of fact the designated initializer is: 
`initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`

Now, for the actual error, Apple [states in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) that:

> **Important**:  This method is the designated initializer for
>   NSManagedObject. You must not initialize a managed object simply by
>   sending it init.

So, you could see that you need 2 things in order to initialize it, an `NSEntityDescription` (which entity you intend to instantiate) and an `NSManagedObjectContext` (the context that the new object will be created into).

Answer (score 4):

Additionaly, if your Challenges class is NSManagedObject and date, rounds and shots are defined as its attributes you can add method:

```
-(void) awakeFromInsert {
     self.date = [NSDate date];
     self.rounds = @(12);
     self.shots = @(5);
}
```

Each new object will have defined those attributes from its birth.

Answer (score 4):

Others have already stated why its not working. Here is how you can cut down on the boilerplate and make your code more readable:

```
@implementation NSManagedObject(MyPrivateAdditions)

+ (id)insertNewObjectInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    return [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:self.className inManagedObjectContext:context];
}

@end
```

now you can do:

```
Challenges *newChallenge = [Challenge insertNewObjectInContext:context];
```