# Failed to call Designated Initializer on NSManagedObject Class -- CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have really been stuck on this issue and I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301250/swift-failed-to-call-designated-initializer-on-nsmanagedobject-class) stackoverflow post but my application still crashes with the issue:

> Failed to call Designated Initializer on NSManagedObject Class

So, I have multiple entities and I have subclassed the `NSManagedObject`. Let's pretend I have entities named: `FirstEntity, SecondEntity, ThirdEntity, Fourth Entity, FifthEntity.` Let's also pretend I have two attributes named `firstAttribute, secondAttribute` in each Entity. I went into the `xcdatamold` opened up the editor and then selected create NSManagedObject Subclass for all of my entities. Then I wanted to instantiate of each of these new `NSManagedObject` Subclasses so I could access the attributes inside the `FirstEntity`. So I wrote this code:

```
let firstEntity = FirstEntity()
```

Then when I run the app it crashes, so I edited it further with a hint from the stackoverflow post and now this is my code:

```
let firstEntityName = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("FirstEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObject)

let firstEntity = FirstEntity.init(entity: firstEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObject)
```

However, my code still is crashing. I am really clueless, because all of the stack overflow posts pertaining to the issue said to do the above, but my code is *still* crashing with the **Failed to call Designated Initializer on NSManagedObject Class** error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not create managed objects yourself through an initializer. Instead, you call NSEntityDescription's `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` function. Along the lines of:

```
let firstEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("FirstEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObject)
```

The above sets firstEntity as an instance of NSManagedObject. Assuming you have created a `FirstEntity` subclass of NSManagedObject through Interface Builder, you can instead use:

```
let firstEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("FirstEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObject) as! FirstEntity
firstEntity.firstAttribute = // Whatever
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. If I do that for some reason the code `firstEntity.firstAttribute` won't work. How would I reference the attributes in each entity using your code?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is this:

- Define in the applicationDelegate a reference for the context
- Instantiate the variable by passing the context

In the AppDelegate (outside the brackets):

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

And in the code:

```
let firstEntity = FirstEntity(context:context)
```

Now you have your entity created. But don't forget to save with:

```
appDelegate.saveContext()
```