# Joining multiple relationships in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entity-relationship, nsmanagedobject

please help.

I have 3 `NSManaged` objects.

**say Employee, Payslip, PayItem**

Each `Employee` can have multiple `Payslips`, each `Payslip` can have multiple `PayItems`.

> so the relationship is Employee <->> Payslip <<- PayItem

They are all set up as `NSManagedOjects`.

Then lets say I have 3 instances of each: (imagine I'm initialising each by adding this to the NSManagedObject class:

```
  convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext)
    {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: <entity>, in: context)!
    self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)'
    }
```

Then I can declare.

```
 var employee = Employee(context: context)
        var payslip = Payslip(context: context)
        var payItem = PayItem(context: context)
```

I can then:

```
employee.addToPayslip(payslip) //Using the function created for me by default.
```

But if I try:

```
payslip.payItem = payItem
```

I always get the error:

> Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class
>   'PayItem'

To summarise, I'm trying to link Employee to a payslip, that is one to many, then a payslip to a payitem, that is one to many. Why am I having such a tough time?

Comment: In my knowledge Create a 3 class Employee , PaySlip and Payitem .          In  Employee class  create an Array of  paySlip property .                                             In Payslip class create an Array of payItem property. just a model .I didnt used NSManagedObject.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I could indeed use arrays of classes. But in this instance. I specifically want to use core data and NSManagedObjects

Comment: The code looks fine. I suspect there is something fishy in your model.

Comment: Me to. I've scoured my model and i just cant come up with the answer. Payslip can join with employee fine, payItem cant join to payslip. Its driving me crazy. Literally weeks i've spent on this.

Comment: The error suggests that somewhere in your code you are calling the plain `init()` method, rather than the convenience initialiser you have created.  This might be in declaring a variable with a default value you never use (as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33307824/3985749)).  If you can't track it down, try overriding the plain `init`, put a breakpoint in it, and then check the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks @pbasdf!!! You were absolutely right. I had in instance of PayItem() being returned from a return I had completely forgotten about and didnt realise was being called. That helped a lot. Weeks of frustration resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out I had a function that was returning an uninitialised version of PayItem. It took a while to track down, but zapping this resolved my problem.