# Unknown crash in Swift 4.0 in iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios9

I am facing very strange crash in my application. Application is working fine in > iOS 10 all version but it is crashing in iOS 9.x versions. I am not able to figure out why this is happening. It is not showing any kind of error in log console or in Zimbie or with evern try catch block.

I am dead lock over here. Any help would be highly appreciated. Here is the image with code with crash. I return multiple types like Int, Int32, Int64 and String but in all cases it is getting crash.

[image]

Comment: add debug point  run again

Comment: @VishalVaghasiya I added debug point and it stops here only.

Comment: Edit your question and add debug log. It seems the problem is in your database file.

Comment: @HassanShahbazi App is completely working in > iOS 10.0 versions. I think if the problem is with DB than it should not work at all. what you say?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem before you share some parts of the code and the debug log. But with a quick look at your screenshot, I can clearly see `CoreData: Failed to call designed initializer on ....`. Maybe you have changed your core data design and yet didn't remove the latest version from iOS 9.3 device?

Comment: I think it not getting return value.

Comment: Line 366, remove `= CDGroups()`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33307824/3985749).

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about core data objects is that they are not 'real' objects with 'real' properties in them.  They are a just an objectId and a pointer to context.  Whenever you access a property of it, it queries it's context with its objectID to get it.

When you have this view of a managedObject some of core-data weirdness makes a lot more sense. You can't have a managedObject without a context so

`... = CDGroups()`

is wrong.